# How to avoid components pushing up/down on one another

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm new to using Java Swing and am looking to produce a GUI that resembles something like this:
[image: crude depiction of goal GUI]

I am pretty close but having an issue where a JLabel pushes up on the grid design like so:
[image: example of pushed up JLabel]

How can I avoid this happening? I place the grid into a GridBagLayout panel and the JLabel into another GridBag panel(plan on putting a JToolbar here too), then add them to the main frame.

```
GridBagLayout tileLayout = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints tileLayoutConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
JPanel tilePanel = new JPanel(tileLayout);
JPanel selectionPanel = new JPanel(tileLayout);
TileButton[][] tileAccessMatrix = new TileButton[4][4];

public BoardUILayer() {
    setSize(1920, 1080);
    buildBoardTiles();
    buildResourcePrompt();
    add(selectionPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(tilePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
private void buildBoardTiles() {
    for (int r = 0; r < tileAccessMatrix.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < tileAccessMatrix[r].length; c++) {
            TileButton temp = new TileButton(r, c);
            tileAccessMatrix[r][c] = temp;
            tileLayoutConstraints.ipadx = 115;
            tileLayoutConstraints.ipady = 115;
            tileLayoutConstraints.gridx = r;
            tileLayoutConstraints.gridy = c;
            temp.addActionListener(temp);
            tilePanel.add(temp, tileLayoutConstraints);
        }
    }
}

public void buildResourcePrompt() {
    final JLabel resourceTextLabel = new JLabel("What resource would you like?");
    tileLayoutConstraints.ipadx = 0;
    tileLayoutConstraints.ipady = 400;
    tileLayoutConstraints.gridx = 50;
    tileLayoutConstraints.gridy = 50;
    selectionPanel.add(resourceTextLabel, tileLayoutConstraints);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the `ipadx` and `ipady` values?  You might consider using a `BorderLayout` as a primary layout for the various other containers

Comment: @MadProgrammer is this in reference to the `selectionPanel`?

Comment: Why all the empty space on the left of the GUI?  Is anything supposed to go there?  You can create a complex `JPanel` by nesting `JPanels`.  I'd show you how if I understood better what you were trying to accomplish with your GUI.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I currently don't have in mind what I want for the empty space, but I would like to have the option of something there.

Comment: You are requesting an additional 400 pixel vertical space for the label (`ipady = 400;`). Do you really need that much vertical space just for the label?

Comment: @ThomasKläger The label initializes to the bottom of the panel. My goal was to have it be further up to accommodate buttons. However, 400 pixel is entirely arbitrary and I used it to examine the pushing on components issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a GUI based on your drawing.  This was one of the most complex GUI's I have ever created in Swing.  The challenge was keeping the `JButton` sizes constant.

[image]

Maybe a `MigLayout` would work better for you.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

I created 11 inner `JPanels` to construct this GUI.

```
JFrame
    main JPanel
        inner JPanel
            turnButton JPanel
                turn JPanel
                buttonGrid JPanel
        resource JPanel
            resourceLabel JPanel
            resourceButton JPanel
    manual JPanel
        outerEastButton JPanel
            eastButton JPanel
```

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RandomGameView implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RandomGameView());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createManualPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        
        JPanel upperPanel = createTurnButtonPanel();
        JPanel lowerPanel = createResourcePanel();
        JPanel innerPanel = createUpperPanel(upperPanel, lowerPanel);
        panel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createUpperPanel(JPanel upperPanel, JPanel lowerPanel) {
        Dimension upperSize = upperPanel.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension lowerSize = lowerPanel.getPreferredSize();
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        int difference = lowerSize.width - upperSize.width;
        int left = difference / 2;
        int right = difference - left;
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, left, 0, right));
        panel.add(upperPanel);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createTurnButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        
        panel.add(createTurnPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(createButtonGrid(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createTurnPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 36f);
        
        JLabel playerLabel = new JLabel("Player's Turn");
        playerLabel.setFont(font);
        panel.add(playerLabel);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonGrid() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 2, 2));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        
        JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[16];
        Dimension buttonSize = new Dimension(100, 100);
        for (int index = 0; index < buttonArray.length; index++) {
            buttonArray[index] = new JButton("Empty");
            buttonArray[index].setPreferredSize(buttonSize);
            panel.add(buttonArray[index]);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createResourcePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        
        panel.add(createResourceLabelPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(createResourceButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createResourceLabelPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 36f);
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Select a Resource");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createResourceButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton[] resourceButton = new JButton[5];
        Dimension buttonSize = new Dimension(100, 100);
        for (int index = 0; index < resourceButton.length; index++) {
            resourceButton[index] = new JButton("Empty");
            resourceButton[index].setPreferredSize(buttonSize);
            panel.add(resourceButton[index]);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createManualPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 300, 20));
        
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 36f);
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Manual");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JPanel eastButtonPanel = createEastButtonPanel();
        JPanel innerPanel = createOuterEastButtonPanel(textArea, eastButtonPanel);
        
        panel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createOuterEastButtonPanel(JTextArea textArea, 
            JPanel eastButtonPanel) {
        Dimension eastButtonPanelSize = eastButtonPanel.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension textAreaSize = textArea.getPreferredSize();
        
        int difference = textAreaSize.width = eastButtonPanelSize.width;
        int left = difference / 2;
        int right = difference - left;
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, left, 0, right));
        panel.add(eastButtonPanel);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createEastButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 2, 2));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        
        JButton[] resourceButton = new JButton[4];
        Dimension buttonSize = new Dimension(50, 50);
        for (int index = 0; index < resourceButton.length; index++) {
            resourceButton[index] = new JButton();
            resourceButton[index].setPreferredSize(buttonSize);
            panel.add(resourceButton[index]);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate it! But I'm still a little lost on how you were able to avoid the different components pushing on each other. Did it end up being my implementation of GridBag?

Comment: @QuantumBlink: I mostly let the Swing layout managers do the calculations for me.  In a couple of places, I had to "help" the layout managers by putting the `JPanel` inside of another `JPanel` so the `JButtons` wouldn't change their shape or size.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help a lot. I plan on using this, so feel free to make a pull request on the repo so I can make sure you get credited. https://github.com/QuantumBlink1337/TownBuilder/pulls

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MigLayout and multiple JPanel.
MigLayout is very easy to use.

Firstly, create a JPanel and add your components to that JPanel.
Secondly, create another JPanel and add your other components to that JPanel.

MigLayout has rows and columns.

```
new MigLayout("","[][][]"/*for ex: 3 columns*/,"[][]" /*for ex 2 rows*/)

this.add(aComponent, "cell 2 1" /*for ex: that component added to third column and second row.*/);
```

For more information: http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html